# css Overflow on the modal window in React JS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using Radix UI to create a modal window:

```
<Dialog.Root>
    <Dialog.Trigger asChild>
      <button className="Button violet" size="large">
        Edit profile
      </button>
    </Dialog.Trigger>
    <Dialog.Portal>
      <Dialog.Content className="DialogContent" style={{ width: "unset" }}>
        <Dialog.Title className="DialogTitle">Edit profile</Dialog.Title>
        <div
          style={{ maxWidth: "300px", maxHeight: "150px", overflow: "auto" }}
        >
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
          <h1>teashabsjkdhkja</h1>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: 25, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
        >
          <Dialog.Close asChild>
            <button className="Button green">Save changes</button>
          </Dialog.Close>
        </div>
        <Dialog.Close asChild>
          <button className="IconButton" aria-label="Close">
            <Cross2Icon />
          </button>
        </Dialog.Close>
      </Dialog.Content>
    </Dialog.Portal>
  </Dialog.Root>
```

When i resize the window from bottom to top over the modal, the  `Save changes` button remains outside the modal, but i want to drag it at the top with the bottom window border.
 Question: How to solve the issue?

 demoL: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hamilton-3bx0h3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the goal is to contain `Button` when resizing the window, perhaps try add `display: flex` and  `flex-direction: column` to the `DialogContent` class in `styles.css`:

```
.DialogContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: hsl(206 22% 7% / 35%) 0px 10px 38px -10px,
    hsl(206 22% 7% / 20%) 0px 10px 20px -15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 85vh;
  padding: 25px;
  animation: contentShow 150ms cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.3, 1);
}
```

Comment: how to create a min height for the content? Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Asking Perhaps a `min-height` can be set to `DialogContent` class but it might need other styles to match the look, for example perhaps the `div` containing `Button` would possibly need `marginTop: "auto"` in its inline styles to match it.